# positioning div's in Bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to archive something like this using Bootstrap:

[image: expected result]

and I'm getting this instead:

[image: current result]

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="layout" class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="min-height: 100px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #4986e7;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #16a765;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-offset-6 col-md-6" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #16a765;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #f83a22;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #fa573c;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #f83a22;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #fa573c;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #ffad46;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: purple;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my CSS:

```
.row {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}
```

I have tried changing margin and padding of div's, have styles inline as well as in separate style sheet, col-lg-*, col-sm-*, but I'm getting the same result. Can  someone point me the right direction, where should I start looking to fix this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vidriduch/qfoLe5vu/7/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<div class="row col-md-12">` - will force every nested item to be inside it.

So when you add another row that you want that shares the previous row (the second green) - you don't want to have it in a new `row` - instead, let it share that same row, remove its offset, and it'll work great!

```
<div id="layout" class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="float: left; min-height: 100px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #4986e7;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #16a765;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #16a765;"></div></div>
    <div class="row col-md-12">

    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #f83a22;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #fa573c;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #f83a22;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #fa573c;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #ffad46;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: purple;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/qfoLe5vu/21/

Answer (score 5):

Hey man I think you just want to nest that second green column inside of the first row col-md-12 instead of having it in its own. Just like this:

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="min-height: 100px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #4986e7;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #16a765;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #16a765;"></div>
</div>
```

Check out my modification to your own fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qfoLe5vu/8/

Comment: +1 thank you. it works, but @docodemore has explained it a bit better.

Comment: You need to make sure he understands the implications of the first green cell becoming too tall: http://jsfiddle.net/qfoLe5vu/25/.

Comment: Yes, thank you Ryan. This is an implication of this specific row and table design. I suggest you share this comment with the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is my HTML
<div class="container" id="layout">
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <div style="min-height: 100px; border: 1px solid white; background-color: rgb(73, 134, 231); width: 50%; float: left;" class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div style="min-height: 50px; border: 1px solid white; background-color: rgb(22, 167, 101); width: 50%; float: left;" class="col-md-6"></div>

        <div style="min-height: 50px; border: 1px solid white; background-color: rgb(22, 167, 101); width: 50%; float: left;" class="col-md-6"></div>
   </div>
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <div style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #f83a22;" class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #fa573c;" class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #f83a22;" class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #fa573c;" class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: #ffad46;" class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div style="min-height: 50px;border: 1px white solid;background-color: purple;" class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/qfoLe5vu/27/)